# Ĉu la pasiva formo "esti x[iao]ta" maloftiĝas favore al la uzado de -iĝ-?

Tags: affixes, language-evolution

Ĉu Esperantistoj pli kaj pli ofte uzas la sufikson ***-iĝ-*** anstataŭ la pasivan formon ***esti x[iao]ta***? Mi havas la impreson ke jes. Mi vidas ofte *prononciĝas* kaj *tradukiĝas*, anstataŭ *estas prononcata* kaj *estas tradukita* kvazaŭ la vortoj mem povus prononci kaj traduki. Ĉu estas alia homo, kiu havas la impreson ke *-iĝ-* pli kaj pli uziĝas, kie la pasiva voĉo estis pli ofte uzata, kaj havus datumojn pri tio?

Comment: Jes. Esperantistoj uzas la vorton "est" malpli ol en la pasinteco.

Answer (score 6):

Mi havas la saman impreson, sed ne povas provizi vin per datumoj. Laŭ mia scio neniu ĝis nun sisteme esploris la fenomenon, kvankam ĝi meritus magistran, se ne doktoran laboraĵon.

Ke *-iĝ-* eniras en lokojn, kie antaŭe oni uzis nur la pasivon, estas efektive tute natura kaj komprenebla evoluo, ĉar ili havas similan ĉefan funkcion, nome montri, ke la sintaksa subjekto de la verbo estas t.n. temo de la ado, do ne aganto, ricevanto, perceptanto k.s.; kp. la ekzemplojn:

- *Mi rulas la barelon* (aganto - ado - temo)
- *La barelo ruliĝas* (temo - ado)
- *La barelo estas rulata de mi* (temo - ado -aganto)

Ĝis nun estas ankoraŭ grava distingo inter *iĝ*-formo kaj pasivo, nome ke laŭ mia impreso oni ĉe pasivo ja povas (sed ne devas) indiki la aganton, dum ĉe *-iĝ-* tio ne estas ebla: * *La barelo ruliĝas de mi* laŭ mi estas malĝusta.

La baza funkcio de *iĝi* kiel sufiksoido dependas de la bazo: Ĉe transitivaj verboj kiel *ruli* ĝi esprimas netransitivon, ĉe aliaj bazoj transiron al la stato aŭ ado: *reĝiĝi* (iĝi reĝo), *ruĝiĝi* (iĝi ruĝa), *sidiĝi* (~iĝi sida = eksidi, ŝanĝi de nesidado al sidado). Ĉe tio ia aganto estas komplete ekster la fokuso, kio klarigas la diferencon al pasivo, kiun mi supre priskribis. Tre belan ekzemplon por tiu specifa uzo de *-iĝ-* troviĝas en la Fundamenta Ekzercaro (§39, mia emfazo):

> Mia onklo ne mortis per natura morto, sed li tamen ne mortigis sin mem kaj ankaŭ estis mortigita de neniu; unu tagon, promenante apud la reloj de fervojo, li falis sub la radojn de veturanta vagonaro kaj **mortiĝis**.

La pasivo laŭ la modelo de la eŭropaj lingvoj havas du bazajn funkciojn, kiuj interdependas:

1. Ŝanĝi la fokuson ĉe la verbaj komplementoj de la aganto al la temo.
2. Ŝanĝi la fokuson ĉe la verbo de ago (kiu **faras** ion) al okazo (kio **okazas**)

El tio oni povas bone kompreni, kial ĝi iĝas ĉiam pli malofta. Por la unua funkcio en Esperanto danke al ties libera vortordo eblas uzi simple frazkomencigon de la objekto (*La barelon mi rulas*), kaj por la dua funkcio konkuras la pli simpla formo kun *-iĝ-*.
Pasivon do oni vere bezonas nur en la maloftaj okazoj, kiam oni volas fokusigi la temon, ne volante/povante uzi alian vortordon, kaj samtempe aldoni la aganton.

Aldono: Estas unu plia diferenco inter pasivo kaj la formo kun *-iĝ-*: Per pasivo oni povas transformi verbojn kun la sufikso *-ig-*, dum tio ne eblas per *-iĝ-*, ĉar (per nevortumita, sed firma) regulo oni ne povas kombini *-iĝ-* kaj *-ig-* en unu vorto, ili sin reciproke forigas. Ekz. *li ruĝigis ŝin* → *ŝi estis ruĝigita (de li)*, sed ne * *ŝi ruĝigiĝis*.